# Django admin: add multiple items from textfield to database

Tags: django, django-admin

I need to make a small app, in which only django-admin is used.

So I have a model with one table, which have one column, let's say table called items, and column name is "name".

I want to have instead of one charfield per row - one textfield. Every line of this textfield will be added as new row to table "items".

edit: would be great to have file upload field also... and then manually parse data

I can't even imagine where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very confusing question.

You have one table called `Items`. The one column in table `Items` is a text field called `Name`. Every row in the textfield `Name` is to be added to the same table as new db rows.

Why would you ever have multiple rows in the textfield `name` if it needs to be split into individual DB rows anyways?

One idea is to set up a ModelAdmin, override save_model, where you hijack the object, never save it, and manually create "Items" as you iterate through the textfield.

### This example works

```
class ItemsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        data = obj.name

        items = [x for x in data.split('\n') if x and not x.isspace()]
        for item in items:
            Items.objects.create(name=item)
```

### As for file field...

There is a file field: `models.FileField()`

But even more for this one you should just set up a single URL & view that is: "/upload-file/" or else you will have a blank FileField on every row in your DB.

If you really really want to use the admin app, override the add_view template and throw in your own upload form and process the file separately

`<input type="file" name="myfile"> + in django view request.FILES['myfile']`

Comment: Because there will be thousands of links just copy pasted, to this textfield.. and those links will came in text file generated by other script, client want's to make this process manualy anyway.. thnx =) ill try this.

Comment: hey holms, my example works, but I just mean it's strange to use the DB save behavior as processing behavior : ) a view and upload url is more natural where you process POST data or something. GL! PS: Updating post with answer to #2 question